# OCaml implementation of two-sum

Tags: performance, algorithm, ocaml, k-sum

I'm implementing some simple algorithms (e.g. two-sum) in OCaml and I am unsure why my OCaml solution is running much slower than the equivalent Python version.

My OCaml version:

```ml
open Base

let two_sum_hash lst target = 
  let rec loop tbl counter = function
    | [] -> failwith "No sum found"
    | x :: xs -> match Hashtbl.find tbl x with 
      | None -> Hashtbl.set tbl ~key:(target - x) ~data:counter; loop tbl (counter+1) xs 
      | Some index -> [index; counter]
  in loop (Hashtbl.create (module Int)) 0 lst
```

and the Python solution

> ```py
>  def two_sum(lst, target):
>     d = {}
>     for i, x in enumerate(lst):
>         if x in d:
>             return [d[x], i]
>         d[target - x] = I
> ```

The OCaml version runs in ~2.16 seconds and the Python solution runs in ~1.15 seconds for large inputs (e.g. list of 10⁷ elements).

What is the reason for OCaml running slower? Am I doing something wrong in my OCaml solution?

I know that dicts are heavily optimised in Python - I wonder how/whether can I make the OCaml code more performant.